# NET Core Webapp (Umbraco) with Windows authentication. Programmatically login user from anonymous controller

Tags: authentication, .net-core, umbraco

I have a .net core web application (Umbraco) with windows authentication enabled.
I defined a location in webconfig to enable anonymous auth for a single Controller.
I this controller i wrote the code to programmatically login a generic domain user.
Everything works fine as I succesfully can login with:

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, true)
```

... then ...

```
_signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(userByName)
```

Last step I try to redirect to the homepage which has windows authentication enabled but the browser keeps prompting for password.
Is there any way to prevent this password prompt? Cause generic user is already logged id (auth cookie is present) or this browser's prompt is part of login challenge and cannot be avoid?